# Repeatability of measurement technique

Tags: anova, repeatability

I'm measuring a person's heart rate based on their position (gradually from laying down to standing up): I tried 8 positions.

Now, I recorded the heart rate of 15 people and I measured them twice.

Two questions I'd like to answer:

1. Is there a difference/trend between the 8 positions?
2. Is the first measurement the same as the second one?

I tried two-way repeated measures ANOVA using SPSS as described here:
https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-repeated-measures-anova-using-spss-statistics.php#procedure

Is this the correct way to go? I'm not sure how to answer question 2 this way.

Answer (score 0):

A two-way repeated measures ANOVA will answer your questions, you will be able to see (1) if there was a difference in the influence of position on heart rate (2) over time (second measurement vs first measurement).

Laerd is a good resource for learning how to compute these kinds of tests, if you follow their instructions you should be good :)